# What is the 'dev' database in Redshift for and why can't I drop it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've created a new Redshift cluster with a database called "my_database" in it. But there is also a 'dev' database that cannot be dropped that doesn't appear to contain anything? When I try to drop the database I get the following error from Redshift:

> ERROR: the 'dev' database should not be dropped [ErrorId: 1-644a6365-4f295a0f62355f3f55816c69]

In the documentation for the `drop database` command [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_DATABASE.html) it states:

> You can't drop the dev, padb_harvest, template0, or template1 databases, and you can't drop the current database

But I can't find an explanation of what the dev database actually is. What is it used for and why can't I drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The databases you listed are automatically created by AWS/Postgres.

I cannot find a detailed description or explanation, but here:

- `dev` is a database created by default whenever a new Redshift cluster is provisioned.
- `padb_harvest` is mostly used for internal operations.
- `template1` and `template0` are both templates that can be used when creating databases. The first template is editable while the second is read only.

So as far as I understand, these cannot be dropped because they're system databases and are somehow required for the functioning of the cluser.